# Exception. Not retrying {:exception=>#<Java::OrgPostgresqlUtil::PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "%"

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, logstash-file, logstash-jdbc

I want to Add My CSV File to postgreSQL.but whenever i try to connect it Show Error:

> [ERROR][logstash.outputs.jdbc
> ][main][a4f714a30e2d2cae8e83b3c2d215c3537fe40dca0495ca92cc2f50a93ba8088a]
> JDBC - Exception. Not retrying
> {:exception=>#<Java::OrgPostgresqlUtil::PSQLException: ERROR: syntax
> error at or near "%"

it is My Config.conf File :

```
input {
  file {
    path => "C:/Users/Desktop/InputData12.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    codec => plain
  }
}

filter {
  csv {
    separator => ","
    columns => ["inputdata","metric","source_table","output_column_alias","method"]
  }
}

output {
  jdbc {
    connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://hostname:5432/database"
    username => "username"
    password => "password"
    driver_jar_path => "C:/Users/Downloads/lib/postgresql-42.5.1.jar"
    driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
    statement => "INSERT INTO csv_to_postgresql (inputdata,metric,source_table,output_column_alias,method) VALUES (%{inputdata},%{metric},%{source_table},%{output_column_alias},%{method})"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that to get a [different error](https://github.com/theangryangel/logstash-output-jdbc/blob/aea74f237cfda3b151dae29cf94b44123c2bc408/lib/logstash/outputs/jdbc.rb#L123) (JDBC - Statement has no parameters). There are two types of statement. If you set "unsafe_statement => true" then the output will [sprintf the SQL statement](https://github.com/theangryangel/logstash-output-jdbc/blob/aea74f237cfda3b151dae29cf94b44123c2bc408/lib/logstash/outputs/jdbc.rb#L220). If you do not set that then you should be using

```
statement => [
    "INSERT INTO csv_to_postgresql (inputdata,metric,source_table,output_column_alias,method) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
    "%{inputdata}",
    "%{metric}",
    "%{source_table}",
    "%{output_column_alias}",
    "%{method})"
]
```

in which case the output will [sprintf all the parameters](https://github.com/theangryangel/logstash-output-jdbc/blob/aea74f237cfda3b151dae29cf94b44123c2bc408/lib/logstash/outputs/jdbc.rb#L270) to the statement. Setting unsafe_statement [can be more expensive](https://github.com/theangryangel/logstash-output-jdbc/blob/aea74f237cfda3b151dae29cf94b44123c2bc408/lib/logstash/outputs/jdbc.rb#L62) than the second approach.